# response string contains <?php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm sending a request for an OAuth service:

```
    $headers = array(
    'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
);
$request = new cURLRequest();
$request->setMethod(cURLRequest::METHOD_POST);
$request->setHeaders($headers);

//#######TO ADD:
//#######SLUG TEST
$fields = array(
    'redirect_uri' => '******custom_cdr/did_conversion/did_conversion/pages/authentication.php',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'client_id' =>  urlencode($config['OAUTH_APP_ID']),
    'state' => '0'
);
$request->setBody($fields);
$response = $request->sendRequest($reqUrl);
$respBody = $response->getBody();
if ($response->getStatus() == Response::STATUS_OK) {
    eval($respBody);
};
```

the response is html (persumably authentication) which starts with php container which I don't know how to print / implement.
The code is not redirecting any where:

```
<?php
$nonce = base64_en

code(mcrypt_create_iv (16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *.hubgets.com; script-src 'self' 'nonce-$nonce' 'sha256-uux/wJCjHlmkdiZXIIoFij3+K7FDO0+C0AJ3Yu+OV4w=' 'sha256-NQYHdO+DXSEnKRsq/w9j6GWfOc5gx1XV7TMQO0NAVFA=' 'sha256-Iw8FmsFJDf8FWS5y6AqfZDJiDVU6yqI7sDVnk8uBj6w=' https://tagmanager.google.com https://js.stripe.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://apis.google.com https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/;");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

```
 <title>Authorize App</title>
<meta name="description" content="Hubgets is a communication and collaboration service that instantly makes your team more collaborative."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Hubgets, communication, collaboration, telephony, instant messaging, presence, mobility, chat, conference, information management"/>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Hubgets" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#0ea5db">
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#0ea5db">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">

<!-- Browser Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" href="./skin.8aef9f1123badd773f06e869e5cb22a140face8a/favicon.ico" />

<!-- Browser Favicon - Firefox Fix -->
<link rel="icon" href="./skin.8aef9f1123badd773f06e869e5cb22a140face8a/favicon.ico" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./skin.8aef9f1123badd773f06e869e5cb22a140face8a/css/hf.css">
```

it also returns a 404 after trying to find a file located in './' compared to a location I don't have on my server

Comment: It looks like the service is simply broken. OAuth does not involve passing PHP source code over HTTP.

Comment: it would be very weird if it is because it's a very big program I am calling